# Reading from file separated with semicolons and storing into array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, structure

I am completely lost and have been trying for hours to read from a file named "movies.txt" and storing the info from it into arrays, because it has semicolons. Any help? Thanks.

movies.txt:

```
The Avengers     ; 2012     ;  89    ;   623357910.79
Guardians of the Galaxy    ;   2014    ;  96    ; 333130696.46
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

struct Movie {
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int rating;
    double earnings;
};

int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    Movie movieList[MAX_SIZE];
    std::string line;
    int i = 0;

    std::ifstream movieFile;
    movieFile.open("movies.txt");

    while (getline(movieFile, line, ';'))
    {
        movieFile >> movieList[i].name >> movieList[i].year >> movieList[i].rating >> movieList[i].earnings;
        i++;
    }

    movieFile.close();

    std::cout << movieList[0].name << " " << movieList[0].year << " " << movieList[0].rating << " " << movieList[0].earnings << std::endl;
    std::cout << movieList[1].name << " " << movieList[1].year << " " << movieList[1].rating << " " << movieList[1].earnings << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is to have:

```
movieList[0].name = "The Avengers";
movieList[0].year = 2012;
movieList[0].rating = 89;
movieList[0].earnings = 623357910.79;

movieList[1].name = "Guardians of the Galaxy";
movieList[1].year = 2014;
movieList[1].rating = 96;
movieList[1].earnings = 333130696.46;
```

Answer (score 1):

I amended your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Movie {
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int rating;
    double earnings;
};


std::vector<std::string>
split(const std::string &s, char delim = ',')
{

    std::vector<std::string> elems;

    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
    {
            elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}


int main()
{

    std::vector<Movie> movieList;
    std::string line;


    std::ifstream movieFile;
    movieFile.open("movies.txt");

    while (getline(movieFile, line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> columns = split(line,';');
        Movie movie;

        movie.name     = columns[0];
        movie.year     = std::stoi(columns[1]);
        movie.rating   = std::stoi(columns[2]);
        movie.earnings = std::stof(columns[3]);

        movieList.push_back(movie);
    }

    movieFile.close();

    for (const Movie & m: movieList) 
    {
        std::cout << m.name << " " << m.year << " " << m.rating << " " << m.earnings << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Basicly, I added a split function that splits the lines using ';'. Also I use vector to store the movies rather than hard coded array of movies. Much better this way.

P.S. Second version without vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Movie {
    std::string name;
    int year;
    int rating;
    double earnings;
};



void split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::string elems[])
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;

    int i = 0;

    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
    {
            elems[i++] = item;
    }
}


int main()
{

    //std::vector<Movie> movieList;

    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    Movie movieList[MAX_SIZE];
    int movieNo = 0;

    std::string line;


    std::ifstream movieFile;
    movieFile.open("/home/marcin/testing/movies.txt");

    std::string columns[4];

    while (getline(movieFile, line))
    {
        split(line,';', columns);

        movieList[movieNo].name     = columns[0];
        movieList[movieNo].year     = std::stoi(columns[1]);
        movieList[movieNo].rating   = std::stoi(columns[2]);
        movieList[movieNo].earnings = std::stof(columns[3]);

        ++movieNo;

    }

    movieFile.close();

    for (int i =0; i < movieNo; ++i) {
        std::cout << movieList[i].name
                  << " "
                  << movieList[i].year
                  << " "
                  << movieList[i].rating
                  << " "
                  << movieList[i].earnings
                  << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I can't use vectors atm? (This is for a class and my instructor wants me to use arrays instead for this assignment). For example, if I had to change "std::vector<std::string> columns = split(line,';');" because of arrays, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @bobtran12 I added second version without using vectors. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! But, it turns out that I can't use stoi and stof either lol (per instructor). Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: You can use stringstream objects to convert string to numeric types such as int and double. You have to google it yourself. I have not time now, to make another version. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline(my_movieFile, movie_name, ';')` to get the name of the movie up to the ;.

You'll need to figure out how to remove the trailing whitespace from the name if necessary.. you can search for examples.

Read the rest of the line using `getline(movieFile, line)`

Use `std::replace` to replace all `;` with a space in `line`

Put `line` into a `std::stringstream`.

Then extract the remaining fields from the stringstream using the `>>` operators.

Put this in loop `do { ... } while (movieFile);`

Also, don't hardcode an arbitrary number of movies. Use a `std::vector<Movie>` and `push_back` to add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to break your line into tokens using something like `std::strtok`. Check out the reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok). The example given on that page uses a blank as a separator, you would use a semicolon.